# How do i output correctly data from a database with php?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, output

I have a database with table called user with 3 columns: first_name, last_name and email. In html i have a form that prompts the user to type some data and are stored in the database. In my index.php page i have a table showing the first name of all the input and when you press the name it opens a new page called output.php that has as output all the information. The problem is that when i press the name it shows the results of all the data there is in the database and not the information about the name i have pressed. When i add the information it works in the database. 
How do you output the data correctly? The code for output.php is:

The code for output.php is:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM user ');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo("<p>First Name:".$row["first_name"]." ");
echo("</p><p>Last Name:".$row["last_name"]." "); 
echo("<p>Email:".$row["email"]." ");
}
```

Comment: You mention a form and user input, what you posted doesn't support what you're asking.

Comment: You should add a `WHERE` clause to that query filtering for the user you want to show.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i just haven’t include here all the html code, will it help if i add the whole code of every page?

Comment: @stickybit how do i add the WHERE clause depending on what user i want to show? I mean i could add a user_id and add the WHERE clause filtering that but how would it output the result depending on what i have typed? If i don’t know the id because it could be a large database with many users so i would want to output the information of the specific id, so how can it be done in php? in mysql it would be easy.

Comment: You said you have a list where you show all users. You should have the ID there and need to pass it to the details view.

Comment: Show us your html page that queries the user information

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you need a `WHERE` clause and since you have noted you only have 3 columns in your user table, you will either need to add an auto incrementing column (named `uid` or `id` or `ID`...etc) and then pass that id to your sql statement from the form OR (not as great but will work) if your email addresses are unique, you can use those as your identifier. If a user can use the same email address in your user table more than once, then you have to make a new column. I would recommend doing an `id` column anyway, but to make it work you can try something like:

**PHP Example Based on Yours**

```
<?php if(!empty($_POST['email'])):
    # Trim the input, to remove spaces/tabs
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    # Make sure this is an email address
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
        # You don't have to die, but I am doing for quickness/ease
        die('Invalid email.');
    else:
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $query->execute([$email]);
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>

            <p>FIRST: <?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></p>
            <p>LAST: <?php echo $row['last_name'] ?></p>
            <p>EMAIL: <?php echo $row['email'] ?></p>

        <?php endwhile ?>

    <?php endif ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <p>Type in the email you are searching for.</p>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
        <input type="submit" value="Select" />
    </form>

<?php endif ?>
```

If you had an id, and output a list of users, you could tack on their id as a query to use `WHERE` on:

```
<a href="/?action=edit&id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">EDIT <?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'] ?></a>
```